# unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'list' and 'int'

Tags: python

Подскажите как исправить ошибку

```
x=2*27**7+3**10-9
a=[]
while x>0:
    a=[a%3]+a
    x=x//3
print(a.count(0))
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:/Users/A-Leo/OneDrive/Рабочий стол/s.py", line 4, in <module>
    a=[a%3]+a
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'list' and 'int'
```

Comment: Что вы пытайтесь сделать?

Comment: Узнать сколько чисел "3" содержится в выражении 2*27**7+3**10-9 записанном в системе счисления по основанию 4

Comment: Вы хотите `a.append((x % 3) + x)`?

Comment: Код приводите текстом. Картинка может выступать в роли пояснения, но здесь достаточно было скопировать текстовое сообщение об ошибке

Comment: [Почему не следует выкладывать код/данные/ошибки в виде скриншотов?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/12120/385375)

Answer (score 4):

Написано, вроде бы, совершенно ясно, красным по английски:

Операция типа '%' не поддерживается для списка и целого.

Ну нельзя делить список на целое! Операция деления - **поэлементная**. Самый простой пример:

```
>>> a = [4,6,8]
>>> b = a /2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'int'
>>>
```

Если вам действительно нужно выполнить такую операцию, распишите это деление через цикл.